# How to resolve dependency inside AuthorizeAttribute with WebApi and Ninject

Tags: authorization, ninject, asp.net-web-api

My current setup is using Ninject for simple IoC, everything goes fine, but I'm not able to resolve one of the classes I need inside my `AuthorizeAttribute`. I need to access a class that does ClaimsVerification:

Here's my code:

IoC Config:

```
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(); // Ninject IoC
        // These registrations are "per instance request".
        // See http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/03/ninject-life-cycle-management-or-scoping/

        kernel.Bind<RepositoryFactories>().To<RepositoryFactories>()
            .InSingletonScope();

        kernel.Bind<IRepositoryProvider>().To<RepositoryProvider>();
        kernel.Bind<ISmartDocumentorUow>().To<SmartDocumentorUow>();
        kernel.Bind<IClaimsVerification>().To<ClaimsVerification>();
       // kernel
        //kernel.BindFilter<MyAuthorizeAttribute>(FilterScope.Controller, 0).WhenControllerHas<RequireRolesAttribute>();

        // Tell WebApi how to use our Ninject IoC
        config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

MyAuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    IClaimsVerification clamisverify { get; set; }

    public MyAuthorizeAttribute()
    {
        //var x = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.(typeof(IClaimsVerification));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yap, sorry, the problem was injecting the iClaimsverification that isn't working in web api..

I tryed with the public property and still it didn't work.

the bindfilter is commented out, because it doesn't exist in the core NInject api (dll), it does exists in the MVC dll of ninject but it works for Action filters in the web mvc, and not in the api mvc for what i can tell..

i do solved the issue like this, though i don't like a lot of this fix:

```
 private IClaimsVerification verifier
    {
        get
        {
            return (GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IClaimsVerification)) as IClaimsVerification);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably best to put this as an UPDATE in your question.

Comment: @Rui Marinho - Hey has a better way been found?

Answer (score 0):

The property you have marked with `Inject` is private - you need to initialize Ninject with a custom configuration to opt into what would be a much less efficient process

(You didnt state the problem in your question. I see you were trying BindFilter, but it's commented out (why?) - this is the correct approach. I recommend reading the Ninject.MVC3 wiki article on BindFilter for an example)

Comment: Yap, sorry, the problem was injecting the iClaimsverification that isn't working in web api..

I tryed with the public property and still it didn't work.

the bindfilter is commented out, because it doesn't exist in the core NInject api (dll), it does exists in the MVC dll of ninject but it works for Action filters in the web mvc

Comment: There is an issue, a pull request or two and an extended discussion on the Ninject GitHub. The Ninject.MVC3 wiki links to one approach that works, but it doesnt directly address managing filters.